# capturing webview as a image snapshot using winjs

Tags: html, winjs, snapshot

I have the following code inside the HTML body that contains several images inside div elements.I would like to capture the whole seen as it is visible on the webview.

```
 <div data-win-control="SdkSample.ScenarioOutput" id="grid">
  <img id ="Img0" src="/images/0.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img1" src="/images/1.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img2" src="/images/2.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img3" src="/images/3.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img4" src="/images/4.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img5" src="/images/5.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img6" src="/images/6.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img7" src="/images/7.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img8" src="/images/8.png" class="GestureTile"/>
  <img id ="Img9" src="/images/9.png" class="GestureTile"/>
 </div>
```

Is it possible to directly capture via winjs or should I approach some other way?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (I'd love to hear otherwise), the only thing that can be captured is the contents of a canvas. I don't think you can captured rendered HTML. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is a bit old, but as of 8.1 you can [grab the webview content as a Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301835.aspx) and then do whatever you need to with it (send it to a server, create a data URI and put it in an `<img>`, etc...

```
myWebview.capturePreviewToBlobAsync().done(
    function(imgBlob) {
        // do whatever you need to with the Blob
    },
    function(err) {
        // handle errors... not sure what you might get here, honestly
    }
);
```

I have not yet implemented this, so I can't say if there are any gotchas.

**UPDATE**

So I tried implementing the above, and this is what it says in the documentation, but it didn't work for me. I'm going to leave it because the commenter below says it works for them. For me, I had to use the code below instead as the `capturePreviewToBlobAsync` method did not return a promise. Not sure why...

```
var myWebView = document.getElementById("theWebviewToCapture");
var captureOperation = myWebView.capturePreviewToBlobAsync();
captureOperation.addEventListener("complete", function (e) {
    var inputStream = e.target.result.msDetachStream();
    // Now you could copy that input stream to a file stream or whatever...
});
captureOperation.start();
```

Check out the [example on this page](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx) (search for "capturePreviewToBlobAsync").

Comment: I have this in a sample in Chapter 4 of my second edition preview book, http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2, and it works just fine. I didn't encounter any eccentricities.

Comment: In your update above, (captureOperation = WAT.options, etc), it seems I need to call the line captureOperation.start(); after.  When I do this, I get an error "JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument."  Experience that or know why it happens.  I can seem to get any of these examples to work.

Comment: @BradleyBossard Ack! Yes, you do need the `start()` method in there (I'll update again). As for the error, I would make sure that the webview element is correct (in my example it was `WAT.options.webView`, but I'll update to be more clear). other than that, I haven't experienced that particular error on this code.