# How can I create 'tab previews' in a Metro app?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

In an Internet Explorer Metro App all open windows are being displayed in an App bar as shown in this picture. My question is, are those tab previews a standard control which I can use in my own app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a standard control.

If you're looking to capture the image as is done with IE, in Windows 8.1 store applications, when using the WebView, you can use the method `capturePreviewToBlobAsync` function to grab an image of the currently displayed content in the WebView.

There's some details about how it could be used here in an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056093/95190

Regardless of how the images are loaded/created, you'll need to handle the layout yourself.